# Performance impact when querying without partition key on a partitioned table

Tags: query-performance, partitioning, mysql-8.0, performance-testing, benchmark

Assuming I partition a table of large size (say 6TB) by month. We are serving very high traffic of around 300 RPS.

Sample schema

```
Create table mydata(
id int not null,
date_created not null,
uuid_val not null,
Primary key (id,date_created),
key uuid_idx uuid_val)
Partition by range(to_days(date_created)
```

What will be the performance impact if I query on this table without date_created in the where clause. It will not give a better performance for sure as it cannot do partition pruning but what will the impact if I query it based on index uuid_val as compared to a non-partitioned table with same schema?
I tried benchmarking it with 6GB data and querying(500,000 times) by index and not partition key the overhead to search in multiple partitions seemed very less (0.1ms) as compared to running the same query on the non-partitioned table.

But why is the overhead so less. Also can I expect such numbers with 6TB data too when serving high traffic?
Can I query partitioned table without partition key as I might not have in the flow.

My MySQL version is 8.

Answer (score 0):

(To many questions to fit in a Comment.)

- I assume that `id` is *not* `AUTO_INCREMENT`?
- Please provide the query; many details could make a difference.  In particular, I cannot answer your "why" without seeing it.
- Also, we need to see the whole `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (you don't need to show all the partitions, just tell us how many.)
- And show us the `CREATE TABLE`  without partitioning -- *The optimal indexes are very likely to be different.*
- If you are looking for a single row by UUID, it will be fast if you have any index starting with uuid.  I would expect a non-partitioned table to be faster since it does not have to check every partition.
- What is the access pattern in your "high traffic"?  For example, are they all looking at a narrow time range?

(Here are some points.)

- If the `WHERE` includes filtering on the "partition key", that will show up in `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  And it should run faster than without the where clause.
- But a revised `INDEX` in a non-partitioned table *may* run faster even with the non-partitioned table.  Example

  ```
  WHERE user_id = 123 AND date_created between ... AND ...
  ```

  begs for the composite `INDEX(user_id, date_created)`
- It is rarely useful to *start* an `INDEX` with the "partition key".